# How can I make / retrieve array from jQuery Call

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Jquery Ajax Call inserts new record on DB. File been called (php) needs to return two values, the contents of the insert and it's id.

How should I send back these values (array, xml, echo) on php?

How will I separate these in the Jquery Ajax success (data)?

Currently the processing php file returns only one string being the inserted content with which I then update view. Need to return the record id so i can wire the element.

Please advice if this needs more clarification. Thank You

**JQUERY**

```
$.ajax({
                    type:'post',
                    url: 'posts_in.php',
                    data: $("#postentry").serialize(),
                    success:function(data){
                        var id='posts';
                        //split returned data here
                        $('<div></div>').attr('id',id).addClass('boxee').html(data).prependTo('#boxer');
                        $('#tittle_ent').val('').focus();
                    }
```

**PHP**

```
echo $value1,$value2;

print_r($arrayhere);
```

XML ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a JSON string encoded with `json_encode()`.

```
$php_array_result = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);

// Send the correct MIME header and echo out the JSON string
header("Content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode($php_array_result);
exit();
```

In your jQuery ajax call, add the `dataType: "json"` property.

```
$.ajax({
   type:'post',
   url: 'posts_in.php',
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data) {
      console.dir(data);
   },
   // etc...
```

Comment: How do I access the return data ? $.parseJSON(data)?

Comment: See addition above.  In the `success` callback function, `data` will be an object from the JSON automatically parsed.  In Firebug, Chrome Developer Tools, or some other debugging platform, `console.dir()` will show you how its contents are organized and you can go from there.

Comment: how can i read response? Firebug returns Response: ["hunx2",389]. Do i still use $.parseJSON()?

Comment: It looks like your `data` is already a JSON object like it should be.  I think you need to access the two values as `Response[0]` and `Response[1]` to retrieve `"hunx2"` and `389` respectively.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that header part, saved me a load of a headache!

Answer (score 1):

How about returning a JSON string?
You use [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) on the server side and use [jQuery.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) on your jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you encode the data back using a JSON encoded array ([json_encode()](http://fr.php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php)) , echo it a the response. [JSON](http://www.json.org) is a standard and common way to pass data back to the client.
Using jquery, you can deserialize the data using `$.parseJSON()`, as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON).